# How to run sed command in ruby script

Tags: ruby

There is a file and I would like to prepend at top of the file. 
file name is xyz.csv

I am able to run the same command in terminal and getting the result as well but when running through ruby script I get an error

*xyz.rb*

```
#Script
file = "/home/sumeet/xyz.csv"
command = "sed -i '1s/^/resource_id,code,value,date\n/'"
full = "#{command} #{file}"
`full`
```

error
`$ ruby xyz.rb`

```
xyz.rb:4:in ``': No such file or directory - full (Errno::ENOENT)
    from xyz.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

The file exists in system

Comment: `\`full\`` attempts to run a command named `full`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string interpolation when you want to use a variable in system calls.  Try:

```
#Script
file = "/home/sumeet/xyz.csv"
command = "sed -i '1s/^/resource_id,code,value,date\\n/'"
full = "#{command} #{file}"
`#{full}`
```

**EDIT:** remember to escape `\` in `\n` using `\\n`. Otherwise it'll be interpreted as a newline and terminate sed command to early.

Comment: `$ ruby xyz.rb`  and i get error 
"sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unterminated `s' command"

Comment: i used `"sed -i '1iresource_id,code,value,date'"` instead but didn't get the result, while same command results in terminal